# Change Crystal Reports Viewer Connection String ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

In Visual Studio 2010, I am dynamically populating a list of Crystal Reports based on an XML file that have the following settings:

```
<Report file="C:\reportname.rpt"    text="Report Name"
       imageURL="~/images/reporticon.png" />
```

In my ASPX page I have a CrystalReportsViewer like the following:

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true"
    Width="800px" Height="600px" CssClass="reportViewer"   HasCrystalLogo="False" />
```

When a user clicks on a report link (Comes from a TreeNode object), the crystal report viewer report is set like the following:

```
 CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = "C:\reportname.rpt";
```

In my actual RPT report files, I have connection strings saved in them so the Crystal Report Viewer does not prompt the user to enter a user name and password.

My question is to find out if it is possible to change the connection string that is saved in the report file? How can I set the connection string information when I load an RPT file into the Crystal Reports Viewer?

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the web viewer is the same as the winforms viewer, but what I ended up having to do was create a new ReportDocument, load the report file into the ReportDocument, and then change all of the connection information.

```
ReportDocument currentReport = new ReportDocument();  
currentReport.Load([path to .rept], OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy);
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

//Set your connection params here  

for (int i = 0; i < currentReport.Database.Tables.Count; i++)
{
    Table crTable = currentReport.Database.Tables[i];
    TableLogOnInfo crTableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
    crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
    crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo);
}

foreach(IConnectionInfo cn in currentReport.DataSourceConnections)
{
    cn.SetConnection(_server, _database, _windowsAuth);        
    cn.SetLogon(_userName, _password);
}
```

Then just set your report viewer source to the report object:

```
CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = currentReport;
```

Comment: Where is crTableLogOnInfo defined?
This looks good, thanks for your help, however, do you know what I should do if I have multiple datasources per report?
Thanks,

Comment: Oops. Edited to define `crTableLogOnInfo` as `TableLogOnInfo` type. I suppose if you have multiple data sources per report, you can inspect each data source as you edit it and make your decision as to where you want to it to now point based off of that info.

Comment: Thanks, I optimally would like to define the connection string in a web.config file, but this does not seem to support that. Is there a way I can easily define whether I am using oracle or Sql server or just swap out the connection string for the one in the web.config file?

Comment: Yea I don't know of any way to swap out report connection types and set their properties using a connection string. In all of our reports we use an ODBC connection so supplying a username/password is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the above code but I get the error "No valid report source available". when I step through the code I get no errors...

Comment: Odd. Like I mentioned before I used this for the winforms version of the viewer so I probably can't help you much beyond this. Hopefully it nudged you in the right direction. I up-voted your question so maybe someone else will have a better answer.

Comment: FYI, I moved my code from PreRender() to the Load even and it started working..............

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub RecurseAndRemap(ByVal CR As Engine.ReportDocument)
        For Each DSC As CrystalDecisions.Shared.IConnectionInfo In CR.DataSourceConnections
            DSC.SetLogon("YourUserName", "YourPassword")
            DSC.SetConnection("YouServerName", "YourDatabaseName", False)
        Next

        CR.SetDatabaseLogon("YourUserName", "YourPassword")

        For Each Table As Engine.Table In CR.Database.Tables
            Table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "YourUserName"
            Table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "YourPassword"
        Next

        If Not CR.IsSubreport Then
            For Each SR As Engine.ReportDocument In CR.Subreports
                RecurseAndRemap(SR)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Again, I tried this in my ASP.NET project and when I get the "No valid report source is available". Thanks for your help though.